# PYTHONPATH from launch.json not visible in Python script (VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, environment-variables, pythonpath

I would like to import methods from a directory one level above my current working directory. One way to do this is to manually append the directory to `sys.path`. I found a better solution for VSCode [on this post](https://k0nze.dev/posts/python-relative-imports-vscode/). The solution described there involves creating a `launch.json` file with a configuration line that looks like `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "/tmp/a:/tmp/b"}`. This method is [documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations). Note that defining the environment variable in `.env` file works, but I would like to use the VSCode variable `$workspaceFolder`, which is not possible in `.env`.

Using `launch.json`, I am not able to access the modified `PYTHONPATH`. In both interactive mode and Run mode, the path doesn't reflect the desired changes.

Following is my directory structure:

```
project/
  - .vscode
     - launch.json
  - conf/
     - file1.py
  - src/
     - file2.py
  - main.py
  - example.py
```

The file `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: main",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "main",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/conf/"}
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: example",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "example",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/conf/"}
        },
    ]
}
```

When I run `main.py` or `example.py`, I don't see the `conf` directory in `sys.path`. What's the correct way to do this?

Example to print `sys.path`:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving deeper into docs and other SO posts, and with hints from [@JaileDu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286232/228177)'s and @[user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76336367/228177)'s answers, I've found the complete solution to the problem in the OP.

For interactive mode, need to add the following to `settings.json` (change `.osx` to respective OS in your case:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"},
"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

For Run mode, set PYTHONPATH in `.env` file ([documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)) or `launch.json` (see the same documentation page and [this blogpost](https://k0nze.dev/posts/python-relative-imports-vscode/)).

---

Some related SO posts:

- [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)
- [How to correctly set PYTHONPATH for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code)
- [How to set the import path for the the Python Interactive window in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654651/how-to-set-the-import-path-for-the-the-python-interactive-window-in-vs-code)
- [add a python path to a module in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812698/add-a-python-path-to-a-module-in-visual-studio-code)
- [Default Python paths when using VSCode interactive window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192732/default-python-paths-when-using-vscode-interactive-window)

Answer (score 2):

> Using launch.json, I am not able to access the modified PYTHONPATH. In both interactive mode and Run mode, the path doesn't reflect the desired changes.

If you're running the file using the play button at the top right or its dropdown entries, or using the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` or `Jupyter: Run Current File in Interactive Window` commands in the command palette, those don't pick on things you put in your launch.json configs as far as I know. You need to actually run the launch config from the Run and Debug View, select the launch config you want to run, and then click the play button in the Run and Debug View.

If you insist on using the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` command, or actions based on that command, you can look into using the `terminal.integrated.env.*` VS Code settings- either in your user or workspace [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). Ex.

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/conf/",
}
```

I'm not sure about workarounds for Jupyter notebooks though.

Comment: Is there a way to pass additional directories to PYTHONPATH while running in interactive mode, or while using the play button on the top right? Maybe I am barking the wrong tree here, but I feel there should be a way to do this. What's the point of all these different modes of running python code if you can't customize what modules you can import. I wonder how others deal with this situation.

Comment: @vpk https://stackoverflow.com/a/76521125/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Your *launch.json* is not matched with your structure. `main.py` and `example.py`is not under the **src** folder in your file structure.

[image]

Modify *launch.json* as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module: main",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "main",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/conf/"}
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module: example",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "example",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/conf/"}
        },
    ]
}
```

Use the green triangle button to debug `main.py` at **Run and Debug** panel, or use `Run --> Start Debugging/Run without Debugging`.

[image]

You better modify the two configurations in Launch to different names, so that it is easier to distinguish to choose from.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JialeDu! I corrected the file locations and made names in launch.json unique. But in interactive mode, I still do not see the change in `PYTHONPATH`. It works fine in Run mode though.